# How can I get read and write permissions to a hard drive in Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, laptop, permissions

I have a rather unique situation:

I have a laptop which boots its Linux OS (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS) from a USB drive.

I also have a internal hard drive installed.

I would like to edit the hard drive, but unfortunately, the drive is in "Read only" state.

The disk has been "salvaged" from a dead Windows based pc (the OS was not installed on that particular drive).

How can I have both Read and Write access to that HDD so i could edit some data in it?

Comment: Your question lacks required information to receive any valuable answer. How is the (internal) drive formatted? What are the permissions on the (internal) drive (user/group) owner(s)? At (least) these 2 questions must be addressed in your original question, to get a *correct* answer. :)

Comment: I have "salvaged" the drive from a dead laptop which ren windows.When running "mount", i can see that the drive's user_id and group_id =0

Comment: You can use `ntfs-3g` to obtain read/write access on that drive. But you'll want to ensure it's `mount`ed read/write in your `fstab` if you choose to mount it automatically.

Comment: I know i can already backup the data i need from the drive, but i need to delete work related data before handing the dead laptop for repair. i would like to do so while preserving the rest of the data, so formatting is not an option.

Comment: If you use the `ntfs-3g` driver(s) I suggested, and `mount` the drive read/write. You will have no difficulty saving, deleting to/from the drive. It will work as any other "native" drive to your system. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install ntfs-3g in Ubuntu (since you use Ubuntu and not Arch), do

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Then find the name of the HDD

```
sudo fdisk -l | grep NTFS
```

Edit the list of drives to be mounted after making a backup copy of the fstab file

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

And follow the examples [in these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions) so the drive will be mounted R/W

Comment: When i try to do that, i get the following error:

'The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)'

Comment: Ok, i got over it by running "sudo ntfsfix". Now everything is fine again =) thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ntfs-3g` to mount the (internal) drive read/write. If you intend to `mount` it *automatically*, make sure your [fstab](https://manpage.me/?q=fstab&manpath=Debian%208.1.0&arch=default&format=html) mounts it read/write.

See [NTFS-3G opensource](https://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/), and [NTFS-3G](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G) for greater detail.